# Extracting text from a div tag

Tags: python, html, regex, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have a list which i'm extracting from beautiful soup using attributes.

```
g_info = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"details_readonly"})
print g_info ## this prints out all the contents of the div tag. 

y = re.compile(r'B00(.{7})',g_info)
print y
```

The list is unsanitized HTML. Somewhere in this list is a text present with a pattern which always begins with B00, it is a 10 digit number which needs to be extracted from multiple pages from the div tag which contains random text.

g_info has a list with all the html contents of the list. This list is something similiar to this:

```
    [<div id="details_readonly" style="">\n<h2>Lorem Ipsum                                    <small></h2>\n                               Lorem Ipsum text <br/>Lorem Ipsum text 

Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem 

Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text 


No<br/> B00EQ0CKRQ <br/>Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text 

Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem 

Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum 

text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text    
</div>]
```

I'm getting an error when i'm trying to find the pattern in g_info using regex  `y=re.compile(r'B00(.{7})',g_info)` :

```
 y = re.compile(r'B00(.{7})',g_info)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 232, in _compile
    p = _cache.get(cachekey)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'ResultSet'
```

Can somebody help me to extract content from the div tag with the pattern mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
g_info = '<div id="details_readonly" style="">\n<h2>Lorem Ipsum                                    <small></h2>\n                               Lorem Ipsum text <br/>Lorem Ipsum text  Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem  Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text No<br/> B00EQ0CKRQ <br/>Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text    </div>]'
print re.search('B00.{7}', g_info).group(0)
```

Outputs:

```
B00EQ0CKRQ
```

**UPDATE:** Using your code:

```
g_info = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"details_readonly"})
print g_info ## this prints out all the contents of the div tag. 

y = re.search('B00.{7}', ''.join(g_info)).group(0)
print y
```

The `''.join(g_info)` will convert the list `g_info` to a string and the regex should work.

Comment: Getting this error on trying trying to execute it. 

`print re.search('B00.{7}', g_info).group(0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 142, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: Thanks i had to type cast g_info into str and then it worked. Thanks

Comment: @bojra: can you tell me what you are doing using the join function ?

Comment: You can that in the answer. It takes everything on the list and converts into a single string. For example, if you have for example a list `m = ["a", "b"]` if you use `''.join(m)` it outputs `ab`.